# Coherent sheaves and Mitchell's embedding theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $S$ be a scheme. By Freyd-Mitchell's theorem the category of (quasi)coherent sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_S$-modules is equivalent to a full subcategory of the category of left $R$-modules for some ring $R$.

Is there a natural construction of such an $R$ using the properties of $S$?

Of course the proof of the theorem would give a category-theoretic construction of $R$ but in the case of schemes i'm wondering if there's a more algebro-geometric construction, maybe in terms of the affine "pieces" of $S$.

In the case of an affine scheme $Spec(A)$, then such an $R$ is obviously just $A$ (restricting to the full subcategory of finitely generated $A$-modules for coherent sheaves), but for more general schemes I find the question interesting. Possibly one would have to restrict to a particular class of well-behaved schemes which includes affine schemes.

Ideally it would be nice to be able to reconstruct $S$ from such a canonical $R$ generalizing how affine schemes are constructed from commutative rings. In this situation then the canonical $R$ for non-affine schemes would have to be non-commutative. But maybe this is not possible.

Comment: "In the case of an affine scheme $Spec(A)$, then $R$ is obviously just $A$" : only if you restrict to the subcategory of quasi-coherent sheaves on $Spec(A)$.

Comment: @abx you're right, should I edit the question?

Comment: Yes, this is always better.

Comment: Edited the question following abx suggestion.

Comment: If $S$ is quasicompact, you can use Zariski descent from a cover by finitely many affine opens.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I'm skeptical about obtaining "canonically" such an R. But I would like to see myself disproved - since QCoh(X) recovers X, such a construction of R might open the door to other cute results.

Comment: Some comments. a) The embedding theorem doesn't work (a priori) for all abelian categories - we need essentially small abelian categories. I suggest to look at the category of quasi-coherent sheaves of finite type (resp. of finite presentation) since that is essentially small. b) "coherent" is something stronger than "finitely generated" (although Hartshorne's book suggests this). c) Even for $\mathbb{P}^1_k$  the question is not easy to answer, I think, even though one understands the quasi-coherent sheaves very well here.